# Intersecting two rasters in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, intersect

I have two raster layers with different resolutions that I want to join.

[image: see this image]

One has higher resolution (transparent yellow) and the other raster has lower resolution but bigger extent (whole earth) and has information about different classes (drawn in different colors here). The resulting raster should have the higher resolution and extent of the raster drawn in yellow here but should be joined with the other raster, e.g. containing the information of what class it was laying within.

Comment: Look at `Con` and `Resample`

Comment: I've just some similar processing and used the CON tool to stamp a cruder scale raster onto a finer resolution raster. Make sure you set the con tool environment settings, cell size and snap raster.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for taking the time to help with your comments! I got the desired result by first resampling to the higher resolution of the other layer and then using the Con(IsNull("Raster1"),0,"Raster2") expression in the Raster Calculator. Maybe this helps in case someone runs into the same issue.